# Can GPL licensed code be close sourced later by the author?

Tags: open-source, licensing, gpl

Suppose someone writes some code, and publishes it as open source under the GPL. Later they decide to close source their application and put it for sale. Is that in violation of the GPL? All code in the closed source app was written by the said author. Since he "owns" the code, I would think he can choose to re-license it however he wishes. Is that right?

Comment: Did you check the FAQ?

Comment: Closest FAQ I found was this, which seems to support the answers: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#ReleaseUnderGPLAndNF

Comment: Lol at the "*To release a non-free program is always ethically tainted*, but legally there is no obstacle to your doing this. If you are the copyright holder for the code, you can release it under various different non-exclusive licenses at various times." :)

Comment: Example application available under both GPL and proprietary licenses: [Ghostscript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript).  Skip to _History_.

Comment: You've got a bunch of good answers already, but the one thing I'll add is that of course, if the author decides to go closed source, the old code is still out there under the GPL, but if he continues to progress the closed source version, the old GPL version will soon start to look quite outdated and lame compared to the "for sale" version.

Comment: see also: [Can you change a license once you pick one?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/55326/can-you-change-a-license-once-you-pick-one)

Answer (score 10):

Yes, if they wrote it, they own the copyright (unless they have assigned that copyright to someone else, of course, like their employer). The GPL confers *extra* rights to non-copyright-holders over and above what copyright law gives them.

The copyright owner is never technically in violation of the GPL since they have all the rights they need under copyright law.

What they *can't* do is to pull back the code already released under GPL, that would be covered by estoppel (basically: if someone does something based on a promise you made, you can't later withdraw that promise - it's an equitable thing).

But they can re-licence their code as much as they want, selling it commercially or even not releasing later versions at all.

---

Keep in mind I am not a lawyer (though I deal with them quite a bit), I am certainly not *your* lawyer, and this advice is worth every cent you paid for it (which is zero).

Comment: Estoppel: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estoppel

Comment: How could someone relicense his code commercially if he has previously **already** put it in the free domain? Aren't licenses either you choose `A` or `B`, but not both? (The OP is talking about his old code that has already been GPL-ed, [not new ones](http://blog.jasonantman.com/2008/01/im-sorry-but-i-dont-like-this-contract-anymore/)).

Comment: @Pacerier The copyright holders are the only parties **not** bound to continue redistribution by the GPL.  This re-licensing happens occasionally, and the copyright holders generally change the version number or the package name to clarify exactly where the licensing change occurred in the timeline.

Comment: @RossPatterson, Hmm, I think there's some real confusion here. So if we release a code as GPL, and we decided we don't want to GPL it anymore, Is the only way we could do to create a new version based on the old one? Are we actually allowed to un-GPL the old code that has already been GPL-ed?

Answer (score 5):

If you own the code and you have GPL'd it, you can't take it back.  The best you can do is grant yourself (or someone else) the right to develop the code further under a closed model.

There was a semi-famous case of a few years back, with some software I actually use called [pchdtvr](http://blog.jasonantman.com/2008/01/im-sorry-but-i-dont-like-this-contract-anymore/).  The guy who wrote it was a pretty good guy, but he tried to revoke the GPL from his code and basically got flamed right off the net. (Angry people basically forced him to shut down his domain, and he disappeared.) You could search for the package or search for his email, `inkling@nop.org`.

So, closing your code and putting it up for sale is no problem.  Trying to stop people from giving away your GPL'd code?  *Big* problem.

Comment: "Flamed right off the net" doesn't sound like a legal procedure

Comment: `pchdtvr` - a good reason why techs should *never* be allowed to name their products :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could try *reading* the GPL. Version 3 is at http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html

The short answer is "NO". The grant of license is in perpetuity. The GPLv3 makes this explicit; earlier versions did not. Legal issues aside, once you've published your source code on the InterTubes with a license saying "go to town", there's the practical issue: how are you going take it back?

> **2. Basic Permissions.**
>
> **All rights granted under this License are granted for the term of copyright
>   on the Program, and are irrevocable provided the stated conditions are met.**
>   This License explicitly affirms your unlimited permission to run the unmodified
>   Program. The output from running a covered work is covered by this License only
>   if the output, given its content, constitutes a covered work. This License
>   acknowledges your rights of fair use or other equivalent, as provided by
>   copyright law.

**Note:** I'm no lawyer. I don't even play one on TV. This advice is worth every penny you paid for it. You need to consult an attorney who knows something about copyright law if the answer to this question is actually important.

Comment: He can't UN-GPL the released code BUT the author does still own the copyright and can additionally use and license the code however he wants.

Comment: "The GPL" is both a contract and an offer for such a contract. The "irrevocable" applies to the contract, not the offer. There are probably laws in your jurisdiction that deal with the withdrawal of offers.

Comment: -1? really...for **quoting** the GPL's own terms?

Comment: No, he can't withdraw the offer either. If he could withdraw the offer, that would prevent any further distribution of the code by new recipients which would defeat the entire purpose of the GPL. GPL section 6 makes this explicit. "Each time you redistribute the Program (or any work based on the
Program), the recipient automatically receives a license from the original licensor to copy, distribute or modify the Program subject to these terms and conditions.  You may not impose any further restrictions on the recipients' exercise of the rights granted herein."

Comment: This probably got downvotes because it fails to separate the two issues of 1) attempting to revoke the GPL and 2) offering a new proprietary version *alongside* a GPL-licensed version. The first case is not possible (as you correctly point out) but the second is fully possible, and your blanket "NO" makes it sound as though it is impossible. Your answer seems indisputably correct insofar as it addresses the question, but it doesn't fully address the question (and tacitly implies an incorrect conclusion for the portion left unaddressed).

Comment: "You could try reading the GPL". Author, please don't bother with sites like stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The author can change their licensing terms at any time for any reason.

What happens to previous revisions of the code that were already distributed to others under the GPL is more of a gray area, however.  The author can indicate that they no longer want their previous versions distributed, but they cannot legally require others to comply with this request.  And in practical terms, once something is out there on the Internet, there's no reigning it back in regardless.

Comment: There's nothing gray about previously distributed code.  @NicolasCarey has the correct answer.

Comment: All the answers here basically say the same thing, but if anyone has _the_ correct answer it's @paxdiablo.  Regardless of what the GPL says or does not say, pulling back code that has been released under _any_ open-source license is legally questionable and practically impossible.  Even if the license explicitly reserves the right to do so.  Once the code is out there, it's out there.  That's a gray area, if you ask me.

Comment: Yeah, I upvoted paxdiablo too.